# Zend view not loading information from controller

Tags: zend-framework

I have zend framework setup .. while my view is loaded it does not dynamically takes information fro the controller

View source from the page looks like :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src=" <?=$this->currentUrl?>scripts/jquery.timers.js">  </script>


<h1><a href="<?=getControllerUrl('default', 'index', 'index')?>" title="<?=SITE_NAME;?>"></a></h1>
```

you can see at run time values are not populated in view. While I dont see any errors and I have verified all paths :(

Please help

Comment: Could you please post your code?

Answer (score 1):

I'll start with, unless you made your own view helpers...

`<?=$this->currentUrl?>scripts/jquery.timers.js">`

should probably be in your layout or view as

`<?php echo $this->headScript()->appendFile('scripts/jquery.timers.js') ?>`

and

```
<h1><a href="<?=getControllerUrl('default', 'index', 'index')?>" title="<?=SITE_NAME;?>"></a></h1>
```

would look much better as

```
<h1><a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'index'), 'default') ?>">title=<?php echo SITE_NAME ?></a></h1>
```

Comment: Missing some quotes around the `appendFile()` argument

Comment: Sorry Guys, I was not able to post the code in this editor for some reason :(

Comment: Hello All, I found the issue, I was trying to deploy the code in wamp server which was suppose to work on zend server. Thanks for all your help and sorry to bother you.